# What does "from A to B to C" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "from A to B to C" mean?

Here A, B, C are nouns or noun phrases.
Maybe it depends on context.
In that case, I would like to know as many different meanings as possible.

I'm particularly interested in that if it can mean from A to B and then from B to C, in other words, if it can mean the order A, B, C in this order.

Comment: Some examples would be better to respond to, rather than some arrangement of A, B, and C. This isn't a math question, after all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the normal meaning of "from A to B to C" is "from A to B, and then from B to C".